# Querying Multiple Database on the same server with same table structure

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a specific problem where I have to query different database to show results in dashboard. The tables that I have to query in those db are exactly same. The number of database can be max 50 and minimum is 5.

**NOTE:** I can't put all the data in same database.

I am using postgres and django. I am not able to understand how to query those database to get data. I also need to filter and aggregate and sort the data and show 10 - 100 results on the search query params.

**APPROACH that I have in mind**

Loop through all database and fetch the data based on the search params and order it by created date. After that take 10 - 100 results as per search params.

I am not able to understand what should be the correct approach and how it should be done considering speed and reliability.

I am open to use any other database for temporary storage. or any other ideas also.

Comment: "NOTE: I can't put all the data in same database." => why ??? (if I may ask ?)

Comment: the requirement is like that. its a multi tenancy project